# Java Chilkat Android: ckhttp crashed on Android > 7

Tags: android, chilkat

Here is my code

public static String getPaypal(){

```
    String result = null;

    result = http.quickGetStr("https://www.paypal.com");    
    
            
    return result;
}
```

When i call this function. Application will get crashed although this function run completely and return the value. The bug occurs on android > 7.

It will not crash if i use http to connect a site with http method instead of https.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on verbose logging and set a debug log file path:

```
http.put_VerboseLogging(true);
http.put_DebugLogFilePath("some_file_path");
```

What would normally be in the http.lastErrorText() will be logged to the file path (created if necessary) specified by the DebugLogFilePath property.

If a crash occurs inside quickGetStr, then you would find an incomplete LastErrorText in the log file.  With verbose logging turned on, it can help isolate the location and context of the crash.  If you find a completed LastErrorText in the log file, then it indicates that the crash did not occur within quickGetStr.